# How can I see the output of geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need a node like the "view" node in the Animation nodes. This is for debugging purpose. If I added two values or used the sin function and I want to check the results are correct or not, What can I do? How can I display the values inside attributes?

I googled and found out that there is no original node made for this. Is there a method to get around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a node tree like this:

[image]

just open the spreadsheet...

[image]

and if you mute the point instance node you will see your values.

[image]

Comment: Worth noting this interface is from 3.0 alpha, it features a "viewer" node in replacement of the monitor icon which is in the top right of nodes in V.2.93. The Geometry domains were also placed in the left hand side rather than popups on the top of the Spreedsheet editor

Answer (score 6):

This isn't quite for displaying attributes, but it's still useful.

The Node Wrangler Add-on has a hotkey for connecting something to the output with a single click. Node Wrangler is one of the built-in add-ons, so if you go to *Preferences > Add-ons > Community*, it should already be there. Simply hit the check mark to enable it.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd> any node that has a Geometry output and it'll connect it to the output, so that you can see what that intermediate step looks like in the Viewport.

[image]

This doesn't work for values like float or int since they are not geometry, but you can just hover over the output or input socket of a node and it'll display the computed value in a tooltip.

[image]

If the tooltip says *'The socket value has not been computed yet.'*, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd> that node to connect a *Viewer Node* (works without Node Wrangler), which will make the value show up in the Spreadsheet. The value will then be computed and hovering should work again (...*if* you have the spreadsheet open, and *if* it is set to *Viewer Node*)

Comment: Relevant documentation on Inspection: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/inspection.html